# StatSVN alternative for Git?

Tags: android, git, svn, statsvn

I'm following the start-up tutorial that [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) gives you which is:

> - Download the latest release of statsvn from http://sourceforge.net/projects/statsvn/
> - Expand the zip file into some directory, e.g `c:\statsvn`
> - Check out a working copy of the desired SVN module into some directory, e.g. `c:\myproject`.
> - Change into that directory and, at the command prompt, type
>
>   `'svn log --xml -v > svn.log'`
> - Change back to the c:\statsvn directory
>
>   type `'java -jar statsvn.jar c:\myproject\svn.log c:\myproject'`
> - Open `c:\statsvn\index.html` in your web browser
>
> You can tweak the output of StatSVN in various ways. Run `'java -jar`
>   `statsvn.jar'` for an overview of the command line parameters, and check
>   the manual for full information.

However, when I try it on a repository such as https://github.com/github/android, StatSVN keeps looping around when trying to output the report.  (It says "completed", then restarts again in 10-20 secs.)

Any help please?

Comment: Subversion and Git are completely different systems. What do you expect StatSVN to do with a Git repository?

Comment: Produce development statistics for the selected project.

Comment: OK, but the question @Chris is asking is this: why do you expect a tool designed expressly for SVN to work with git?

Comment: Hi alroc. I thought SVN could work for the .git repository.

Comment: +1 to negate the downvote: The question is logical because of SVN support in GitHub.  Also: StatSVN really does its work using log output from SVN as input (a text file) so the SVN 'aspects' of it are perhaps not so important.  The output from StatSVN is more thorough than what you see in gitstats mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want: http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/

statsvn was written for svn. not git. it does not support git. the error was bound to happen.

Comment: So apparently you can change the URL get type to Subversion. I just had to change it to Subversion instead of git. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @Eggy, you should add an answer based on your comment with more detail for clarity. While the accepted answer mentions GitStats, which is great, it also leaves one with the impression that StatSVN cannot work with Git(Hub); but your comment leads one to believe that this is not (always) true, _which is important_. An example of a "before" URL (i.e. that doesn't work with StatSVN) and corresponding "after" URL (i.e. that does) would be great. Also, qualifying the answer - e.g. that it only applies to GitHub rather than Git repos generally would be helpful.

Comment: Ok. In Github.com , when you are on a repository (i.e. take Androids GitHub repository), you can set the checkout URL for the repository to Subversion. For instance here https://github.com/github/android , in the mid-right of the screen you can select "Subversion", "HTTPS" or "SSH" checkout URL. Hope that's a clearer answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Another tool which may be helpful is [statgit](https://github.com/soundasleep/statgit/), a project that I've just started which tries to generate statistics similar to StatSVN.